# Independence of product $XY$ of independent real-valued random variables $X$,$Y$.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ such that $P_X,P_Y=\dfrac{1}{2}(\delta_1+\delta_{-1})$. Show that $X,Y$ and $Z=X\cdot Y$ are pairwise independent but not independent.

Well, I'm already struggling to show their pairwise independence. I'm not quite sure how I can get $P_{XY}$ from $P_X,P_Y$ to start with.

Comment: There is not enough information about the problem as you have stated it. Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be independent? If so, $P_{XY}(x,y) = P_X(x)P_Y(y)$.

Comment: Oh yeah I totally forgot typing that

Comment: $X,Y$, and $XY$ are not independent because
$$
0=\mathsf{P}(X=1,Y=1,XY=-1)\ne\mathsf{P}(X=1)\mathsf{P}(Y=1)\mathsf{P}(XY=-1)>0.
$$